# Is it correct to say "don't go Err like that before talking"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

One problem of my daughter is that she often says "**Err Err Err**" for a while (3 or 4 seconds) before saying a full sentence.

Probably, she makes that sounds because she can't remember the words right away.

I don't think she stutters because she does not repeat the first sound of some words several times.

Is it correct to say "**don't go Err like that before talking**" or do we have a more common way of expressing it?

Comment: Interjections in English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection#Examples_from_English "Er" is used for hesitation. But not: err.

Comment: I was looking at the questions you ask. A recent one had five positive votes. You might think about rewarding people's efforts on your behalf....

Comment: You could say "Don't [hem and haw](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hem%20and%20haw)", but your way is fine too.

Comment: Don't stutter. I guess you can see these developmental tendencies (using filter words more often than needed) as mild, passing forms of stuttering.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  Maybe your dialect is different from mine, but in mine, filling time with "Er..." before saying something isn't stuttering.  Stuttering is more like going "D-d-d-don't s-s-say things like that."

Comment: @stangdon yes, you are right. I confused [speech disfluency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_disfluency) with stuttering.

Comment: Your sentence is fine (following Lambie's spelling correction above).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is grammatically correct, but I wouldn't say it to any of my offspring. It probably just means that your daughter is organising her ideas rather than just blurting out the first thing that comes into her head. Also, it's a normal facet of speech:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_disfluency